# Forms Authentication with NancyFx

Tags: authentication, nancy

I am using [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/) to make a simple website were users can login and out using an ajax control.

I have read the documentation on [Forms Authentication with Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Forms-Authentication) and I think I have completed all the required steps.

1. Install the Nancy.Authentication.Forms package
2. Implement an IUserMapper
3. Implement routes to handle login and logout
4. Configure and enable Forms Authentication

I am having an issue where after calling login, requests do not have a current user set.
I can see a cookie set after the login is executed. However the user mapper is not getting called. I have tried requesting routes with and with out the this.RequiresAuthentication(); and still no user.

Here is my Bootstrapper Implementation for step 4

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        container.Register<ISessionFactory>((c, p) => SessionFactory.Factory);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions conventions)
    {
        base.ConfigureConventions(conventions);

        conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("assets", @"content/assets"));
        conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("application", @"content/application"));
    }

    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);
        container.Register<IUserMapper, UserMapper>();
    }

    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);

        var formsAuthConfiguration =
            new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration()
            {
                RedirectUrl = "~/",
                UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>()
            };

        FormsAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, formsAuthConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Here is my login & logout logic for step 3.

```
Post["/login"] = x =>
        {
            //Verify here, hardcode for testing
            string email = "test@example.com";

            User user = ExecuteCommand(new FetchUser(email));

            this.LoginWithoutRedirect(user.Session);
            return new { email = user.Email, authorized = true, status = "okay" };
        };

        Post["/logout"] = x =>
        {
            return this.Logout("~/");
        };
```

My IUsermapper simply looks up a user from a database with the given id.
I can see it gets constructed when the RequestStartup resolves the IUserMapper but then there are never any calls to the get GetUserFromIdentifier function.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetUserFromIdentifier` method is not being called because you are using the `LoginWithoutRedirect` extension. It is not the login that calls `GetUserFromIdentifier` but rather any subsequent redirect.

A more usual way of doing things would be:

```
string email = "test@example.com";
User user = ExecuteCommand(new FetchUser(email));
this.LoginAndRedirect(user.Session);
```

It is not expected that the login route would be accessed directly. Instead the user would normally request a protected resource, be authenticated and then redirected to the requested resource.

A couple of other points:

When I tried your code I got an error returning an anonymous type. Instead I needed to return the type as json, like this:

```
this.LoginWithoutRedirect(user.Session);
return Response.AsJson(new
{
    email = user.Email,
    authorized = true,
    status = "okay"
});
```

This works fine, it logs in and returns your anonymous type as a json object and since there is no redirect then, as expected, it does not call `GetUserFromIdentifier`.

Finally, your `/logout` route should be protected using `this.RequiresAuthentication()`. It makes sense because only authenticated users need to logout. It will also protect you when  `GetUserFromIdentifier` returns null - perhaps because a cached user has been timed out. `RequiresAuthentication` detects this null user and redirects back to `Get["/login"]`.

Comment: Good point on the logout handler. I had no troubles returning an anon type, I was getting it back as an object on the front end. The key to this issue is you have to do the redirect, you can't call login and return your own data instead.